# Dúvidas sobre estrutura de branchs e repositórios

Tags: git

Estou começando a estudar e usar os DVCS (programas de versionamento: GIT, mercurial).

Tentei remontar uma estrutura de pastas, usando branches mas o resultado não foi o esperado. Queria entender como funciona a estrutura.

O que fiz foi seguinte:

Abri um rep no gitbucket:

```
xyp
```

Tem o branch master, e criei 5 branches: b1, b2, 3b, b4 e b5

Baixei para minha máquina em uma pasta, fiz um `clone`, colei uma pasta [b1] dentro dessa pasta, acessei o ramo com o mesmo ramo:

```
git checkout -b b1
```

Depois:

```
git add *
```

Para adicionar os arquivos novos no tal ramo, e depois commit:

```
git commit -m "1 commit b1"
```

Depois dei push:

```
git push https://*******@bitbucket.org/*****/******.git
```

E fui fazendo assim nos 5 casos imaginando que teria seguinte estrutura nos ramos como as as pastas:

```
             masters
b1  b2 b3  b4
```

Só que quando olhei os branches no gitbucket, a estrutura estava toda torta:

- 1 commit b1 ficou com 5 branches dentro [b1  b2 b3  b4 b5]
- o 2 commit b2 ficou com 4 branches dentro [b2 b3  b4 b5]
- o 3 commit b3 ficou com 3 branches dentro [ b3  b4 b5]

E assim sucessivamente. E o último ficou com um, apenas com ele mesmo

```
commit b5 (b5)
```

Porque essa estrutura estranha não ficou de acordo com o que pensei e estruturei?

Comment: Se você quer que cada branch saia da `master`, antes de criar um novo verifique onde está, pois será criado a partir de onde esta, se for criar a partir da `master`, teria que sincronizar a master e depois criar o branch.

Comment: Entrando no modo grafico no gitbuckt aba branches e listando eles aparece essa estrutura, isos que achei estranho

1 commit b5 1 Branches dentro deles aparece [b5]

1 commit b4 2 branches dentro deles aparece [b4 b5]

1 commit b3 3 branches dentro deles aparece [b3 b4 b5]

1 commit b2 4 branches dentro deles aparece [b2 b3 b4 b5]

1 commit b1 5 branches dentro deles aparece [b1 b2 b3 b4 b5]

o que esperava era como idealizei

1 commit b5 1 Branches [b5]

1 commit b4 1 branches [b4]

1 commit b3 1 branches [b3]

1 commit b2 1 branches [b2]

1 commit b1 1 branches [b1]

Answer (score 0):

> E fui fazendo assim nos 5 casos imaginando que teria seguinte estrutura nos ramos como as as pastas:

Aqui está o problema: o que você fez após isto.

Provavelmente, você fez o seguinte:

```
mkdir b1
git checkout -b b1
git add *
git commit -m "1 commit b1"
git push
```

Depois disto, ao invés de voltar para a branch `master` e criar a próxima branch a partir dela, você continuou:

```
mkdir b2
git checkout -b b2
```

E etc, criando uma estrutura assim, com uma branch criada a partir da última branch:

```
                                  .---05
                                 /
                            .---04
                           /
                      .---03
                     /
                .---02
               /
         .---01
        /
  00<--´
```

E não como gostaria:

```
               .---05
              /
             .---04
            /
           .---03
          /
         .---02
        /
  00<--´---01
```

Que seria feita criando todas as branches a partir da branch `master`. Portanto, faltou, entre os comandos de `push` e `mkdir`, um:

```
git checkout master
```